Opening Secure Websocket from Javascript in browser
My system has two servers

A custom boost::beast based secure websocket server listening on port 887
Standard HTTPS server (apache2) listening for connections on port 443. It serves

one HTML file which references a JavaScript file
the client certificate and key (yes, I know it's not secure, but that's not the critical part for this question)
the JavaScript file attempts to open a secure websocket on port 887 using the client cert+key



The intention is for a user of this system to point their browser to the HTML page on this server and have the browser do its thing, which starts with opening the secure websocket.
I have validated my secure websocket server and certificate chain of trust using openssl s_client and I know that the server correctly validates client certificates. However, when the following JavaScript code runs in the browser, the secure websocket server rejects the connection with "sslv3 alert certificate unknown" handshake error.
'use strict'

window.onload = async function () {

  // N.B. all DOM element stuff is purely for debugging purposes.
  const div = document.getElementById('mainContainer');
  div.innerHTML += 'Beginning of life<br />'; 

  const cert_response = await fetch('wss-client.crt');
  const key_response = await fetch('wss-client.key');
  const certVal = await cert_response.text();
  const keyVal = await key_response.text();
  div.innerHTML += certVal + '<p />';
  div.innerHTML += keyVal + '<p />';

  const options = {
    key: keyVal,
    cert: certVal
  };

  let socket = new WebSocket(
          'wss://' + window.location.hostname + ':887',
          ["soap", "wamp", "sip", "amqp", "mqtt", "xmpp"], // I'm guessing here
          options);
  socket.onopen = function(e) {
    div.innerHTML += 'opened socket<br />';
  };
};

The JavaScript code for opening a websocket with "options" is based on [this Websocket class documentation][1] which mentions that "options" can be anything accepted by https.request and that documents how to [specify cert+key here][2].
Full disclaimer, I'm not overly proficient in JavaScript (my background is primarily C/C++), so I could be missing something fundamental here.
  [1]: https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md#class-websocket
  [2]: https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback


You don't need any options on the client side, just the URL.

const cert_response = await fetch('wss-client.crt');,  yeah, you don't do any of that either.   If the server certificate is not from a trusted authority, then the browser will ask if you wish to continue, you don't have any options from Javascript using self signed certificates as been trusted.

I don't think there is any support for specifying client certificates as you do with Javascript running in the browser. There is not even an argument for TLS options - see https://websockets.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-dom-websocket-websocket%E2%91%A0

<p /> ?? ParagraphElement is not a void Element
